# Android: User Interface

Tags: android

I am working on an android app and I have to Implement the below screen. That screen has two buttons at the top just like we have in tab view, on changing the button 1 is for opening the Picture view and other is to view the videos screen. Below that buttons I have to Implement two `listviews` for video screen that will each contain one header like `one` for songs (below that will be a `listview` of songs) and `second` header is for films (below that will be a `listview` of films). And the data for both songs and films is coming from two different `services`, just like for songs `http://mywebsite.com/songs`  and for films `http://mywebsite.com/films`. Now I am little bit confused about the `UI` that there are many alternatives to implement it, but not sure which one will be best for me.

Please give me some ideas about how to implement it. Should I use a Radio group for the above buttons and on State change it should call the respective method, for a view of video and picture. But for each view I will have to make two `listviews` , just like in the video screen one for songs and other for films. And making two `listviews` is little bit complex than a single `listview`. `Is there any way to handle it by only one adapter and in that view the same headers should be there`. Ad if someone has any good idea then please share it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to use fragments for your tab functionslity.

An alternative for two list views could be one [expendablelistview](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/). With two groups. You can add multiple types of items to any list view. You just have to overwrite the getitemtype Methode and define the different types you want to display in your listview.

Comment: as you said _"You can add multiple types oft items to any list view. You just have to overwrite the getitemtype Methode and define the different types you want to display in your listview"_. Can you please give me some link to an example or code?

Comment: and using expandable `listview` there will be problems of empty space between groups. b.coz it also effects the childs when you do a background color as in my case.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial about listviews in general which also covers expendablelistviews: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
You should be able to style the group spacing to no spacing by using a custom listview style

Answer (score 0):

1) hey bro, firstly u hv to create a swap view with a navigation tab functionality on it. check out this link http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

2) the above example will provide you 2 fragment pages that you can use for picture and videos separately. You can create the layout of every page as you like via using separate fragment with their own layout as you wish.

3) Now in video layout fragment, you can use 2 list views one by one in the linear layout with orientation vertical. Check this link to get idea how to implement your custom list view. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

4) You have to put the value of Android:weightSum="2" in parent layout( linear layout with orientation vertical) and put Android:layout_height="0dp" & Android:layout_weight="1" in each list view. This will provide equal space for both the list view in single screen for each type of device.